# Please help on thermal Pad measuring

Tags: thermal-pads

I am replacing the thermal pads of my laptop. Namely, it uses six thermals pads:

- One on the gpu
- One on the northbridge
- Two on the video memory
- Two on the VRM

(Plus thermal compound on the cpu)

The original pads from the manufacturer (or last technician who repaired it) have the following thickness:

- 0.5mm on the gpu
- 1.5mm on the northbridge
- 1.5mm on the video memory
- 1.5mm on the VRM

Surprisingly, when I measured the gaps using a feeler gauge, I realized that the pad on the northbridge was particularly thick compared to the gap. The gaps according to my measurement are:

- 0.35mm on the gpu
- <0.02mm on the northbridge
- 0.5mm on the video memory
- 1mm on the VRM

So my laptop was using a 1.5mm pad on the northbridge while the actual gap is less than 0.02mm.

What thickness of thermal pads should I use on each one?

Also, what sizes should I cut the pads once I decide the thickness? Should the pads be exactly the size of the chip part touching the heatsink? Or should they be smaller/larger?